# If a local store holds a "Christmas Sale" in the days leading up to Dec. 25th, may I shop there?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, transactions, non-jewish-holidays

## My question

In mid-December, I received the weekly advertising flyer of a local store chain.  At the top, the flyer said "Christmas Sale".

If a sale is advertised like this, with the name of a non-Jewish religious holiday explicitly in the title, is it permissible to shop at the sale, and to benefit from the sale?

Please base your answer upon sources, and please cite them.

[Note:  Before following any answers that get posted here, [ask your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).]

---

## Related

1. A question by DanF:  ["When a chain store adverises a 'Holiday' or 'End of Year' sale, may I buy their product?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66406/when-a-chain-store-adverises-a-holiday-or-end-of-year-sale-may-i-buy-their)  DanF's question seems to be about stores which are less explicit in naming their sales.
2. ["Buying from non-Jews, or selling to non-Jews, within three days of their holidays"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66465/buying-from-non-jews-or-selling-to-non-jews-within-three-days-of-their-holiday).

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.1.1

Comment: This is an interesting question. I get the Talmud reference from @DoubleAA. However, what one might analyze in this is the actual intent of a large store chain (or just about anyone, for that matter) advertising a sale. Is it just specifically to celebrate the holiday, or are they in general making a sale and the holiday season is incidental to the sale? Many Jews buy cars this time of the year b/c it tends to be significantly cheaper now. Do they have to avoid going to the dealer beginning next Wed.?

Comment: @DanF: Good question. I'd be curious to know the answer to that too. Mind to please post a separate question and to provide me with a link?

Comment: Note that they are not worshiping the avodas zara but trying to takr advantage of the non-Jewish superstitions to get them to buy.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Yes. Some related resources: The [Background to the Daf](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/azarah/backgrnd/az-in-002.htm), which explains the reasoning. And the [Outlines of Halachos from the Daf](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/azarah/halachah/az-hl-002.htm), which (partway down the page) cites the Rambam, the Shulchan Aruch, and others. But please note that today is December 18; it's more than three days away from their holiday.

Comment: @unforgettableid Was your question only about going on December 18th? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: @sabbahillel See ^^^. It may refute your assumption.

Comment: Many supermarkets place advertisements in their windows for unkosher food items like pork, shellfish, non-kosher meat, etc. In addition, they may have Happy Easter, Halloween, etc., banners. Would that mean you could not purchase kosher-certified products from the supermarket? If so, many Orthodox Jews, at least in Brooklyn, do not seem troubled by doing so.

Comment: @JJLL:  Even if they have a pork advertisement in their window, I see no problem.  And even if they wish us a good holiday, I still see no problem.  But if they make a claim that we're saving big bucks because of their holiday, _then_ I fear it may be a problem.

Comment: Functionally, the issur is regarding providing money to a non-Jew that subsequently will be spent towards the worship of AZ. The employees (and even the owner) of a store generally do not directly benefit from the purchases of the individual - it goes to the incorporation of the store which then disperses funds to the employees. We must then consider whether the legal fiction of the corporation can be designated as having religion in order to declare purchasing from the store a benefit to AZ.

Comment: @DoubleAA: The mishnah you cited doesn't apply unless it's within three days of the holiday. And, even then, it's [not so clear](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66465/buying-from-non-jews-or-selling-to-non-jews-within-three-days-of-their-holiday) that it applies anymore nowadays. My question was whether or not it's permissible to shop at such a sale at all, even if there's still one full week to go before the holiday itself.