# When a chain store advertises a "Holiday" or "End of Year" sale, may I buy their product?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, transactions, non-jewish-holidays

My question is related to [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66400/5275). The linked question focuses on the phrasing in the ad of referring to "Christmas", so it seems obvious that they are referring to a specific holiday.

My question is a bit generic. Many chain stores decided to become politically correct and don't want to offend those that don't celebrate Christmas (I'm apathetic either way) so they call it a "holiday" or "end of year sale". It's pretty obvious which holidays they are referring to, anyway.

[This Mishnah](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.1.1?lang=en&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) says not to do business with non-Jews 3 days before their holiday. IIRC, the Gemarrah specifies that we don't want to give them pleasure and give them money that they can use to celebrate their idol-worship-associated holiday.

My question relates mainly to chain stores like Macy's and Wal-Mart as well as buying from a car dealer.

One can argue that they are just making a sale and the holiday season is incidental or an incentive. It seems a bit more obvious with car dealers as their main incentive is to clear their inventory before the end of the year (as a dealer explained to me.)

So related questions, here:

- Does it make any difference if the advertising mentions that the sale is for Christmas specifically? What if the sale extends before or after the holiday?
- What if what one buys is used for a mitzvah purpose, even indirectly? For example, a person attends weddings and other simchot frequently, but to do this, he needs a car to get there. He currently doesn't own a car. Can he buy one during this time?

Comment: Why is the mishnah that says not to do business with non-Jews 3 days before their holiday relevant to this question? It's 3 days before their holiday regardless of whether they offer a "holiday sale."

Comment: Also how is this not a duplicate of the linked question? The title is different, but then the body of the question basically just asks the same thing.

Comment: @Daniel within this question and a view of the Gemarah, IIRC, is a question of intent. Does the sale, itself, indicate a celebration of a holiday? Related, regarding chain stores or car dealers, how would you know if the "company" or owner of it (it's ususally publicly owned by stockholders) falls into the celebration of any holiday?

Comment: Additionally, stockholders (the beneficiaries of the corporation/store) receive dividends/benefits in either quarterly, semi-, or annual periods. By the time the money "gets to" the prospective non-Jew it is significantly AFTER the holiday in question. Can a person make a contractual purchase on credit with a non-Jew close to a holiday if the actual money will be transferred months later? I would think so. Conversely, does the capacity for the non-Jew to use your contract as a lien to purchase things for himself "on credit" potentially violate the same prohibition? Possibly.

Comment: +0. "a=incidental or an incentive" doesn't make sense. "t says" and "canone" are typos. "Gamarah" is an odd transliteration. And the question needs a good few minutes of additional copyediting in general. Plus, you've bundled too many questions into one post. Finally, please depersonalize your post if possible. Good questions though.

Comment: @unforgettableid .. and you have made some unforgettable suggestions on my carelessness. I've edited the question. Thanks for your suggestions.